# Yii2 add LIKE condition with "%" wildcard on the one side

Tags: mysql, yii2

I want to add `like` condition with `%` wildcard on the one side, like:

```
where name like 'value%'
```

My code:

```
Table::find()->filterWhere(['like', 'name' , $_GET['q'].'%' ])
        ->all();
```

But query result is:

```
 where name like '%value\%%'
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You need set the fourth operand to `false` in order to use custom where like conditions:

```
Table::find()->where(['like', 'name', $_GET['q'] . '%', false]);
```

From the [docs](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-queryinterface#where()-detail):

> Sometimes, you may want to add the percentage characters to the
> matching value by yourself, you may supply a third operand `false` to do
> so. For example, `['like', 'name', '%tester', false]` will generate `name LIKE '%tester'`.

Comment: why i bind $_GET['q'] in param 
isn't the where automatic escape it's parameters ?
and if i want to add it in the params how to do this ?

Comment: Yes, the operator format will auto escape the input.

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

```
Table::find()->where(new \yii\db\Expression('name LIKE :term', [':term' => $_GET['q'] . '%']));
```

or

```
Table::find()->where(['like', 'name', $_GET['q'] . '%', false]);
```

or

```
$likeCondition = new \yii\db\conditions\LikeCondition('name', 'LIKE', $_GET['q'] . '%');
$likeCondition->setEscapingReplacements(false);
Table::find()->where($likeCondition);
```

More info at https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-conditions-likecondition

Comment: Yes. Fixed. Thanks.